# Material Design typography on tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have been developing an Android APP with material design guides.
But i cannot understand what text sizes i should use on tablets. I was looking to this  [Typography - Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-styles), and cannot find any specification.

On other away, i have been looking to this [Metrics and keylines - Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing), and they separate tablets for phones

I used the sizes that was on first link, but on tablets they are to small.
Since they have metricss for phones an dtablets, why they dont have textsizes for phones and tablets?

Thanks

Comment: The screen size on a tablet is different, so the layouts are different. There is no reason to have different font sizes on a tablet. It is used from the same viewing distance as a phone.

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand what you mean... Yes layouts are differentes, thats why google specify diferent "dp" for layouts. But font size in "sp", they didnt made any diferences..
So, i tried with same "sp", but on tablets they are to small..Thats why,im asking if there are not specification for typography on tablets like they made on layouts

Comment: Tablet apps are not just scaled-up phone apps. The text sizes in Material were specified based on viewing distance. It has nothing to do with screen density. The text is not supposed to be any bigger on a tablet-sized screen.

Comment: You should do whatever is appropriate for your app. I am only answering the question of why text sizes in Material were not specified differently for tablets.

Comment: @user1851366 Please have a look at this.https://github.com/intuit/sdp . Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

First some clarifications "Scale independent pixels" or "sp" take in consideration not only the difference in density but also the user preferred text size. So they work just like "dp" with the difference that when the user set his preferences to larger text all "sp" will appear larger.

I recommend you to have a "values" and "values-large" folder with "dimensions.xml" file, the first one will have the normal sizes and the second the bigger ones to use in your layout, the "values-large" will only be use on large screens like tablets.

Hope this helps.
Regards Jose

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Download the Source from github.com/intuit/sdp. You could either **copy all the values from sdp to your project** or **Convert the sdp to library project and add it to your project.**

**To make the library project:**

Delete all the java files from src . Right click project ---> Properties ---> Android ---> Check isLibrary. And then add it as a library project.

Comment: On android studio just add sdp to your dependencies. e.g. dependencies {
  compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
}